# JBoss Tools editor in Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0) broken

Tags: eclipse, jboss, xhtml, editor

I had a Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2019-12 (4.14.0) on Win 10, along with JBoss Tools 4.14.0 Final installed form the marketplace. This morning I've got an update notification in eclipse and I have accepted it without properly reading what it was about. I turned out to be an major update to version 2020.03 (4.15.0). After the update every thing seemed OK on the first sight, however when I tried to open an xhtml file it did not open?! In the eclipse log file I have found the following:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2020-04-16 17:34:19.681
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/ElementContainer/selectedElement/SET] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl@7a13ad55 (tags: [org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack, EditorStack], contributorURI: null) (widget: CTabFolder {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer@3f1b4a14, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null), Widget=CTabFolder {}, org.eclipse.e4.data={ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartStackImpl@7a13ad55 (tags: [org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack, EditorStack], contributorURI: null) (widget: CTabFolder {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer@3f1b4a14, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null), AttName=selectedElement, EventType=SET, Widget=CTabFolder {}, NewValue=org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl@7e2e1021 (tags: [Editor, removeOnHide, org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.HTMLTextEditor], contributorURI: null) (widget: ContributedPartRenderer$1 {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer@3d5a6c07, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (contributionURI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor, object: null, context: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.HTMLTextEditorContext, variables: [], label: null, iconURI: null, tooltip: null, dirty: false, closeable: true, description: null)}, AttName=selectedElement, NewValue=org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl@7e2e1021 (tags: [Editor, removeOnHide, org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.HTMLTextEditor], contributorURI: null) (widget: ContributedPartRenderer$1 {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer@3d5a6c07, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (contributionURI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor, object: null, context: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.jboss.tools.jst.jsp.jspeditor.HTMLTextEditorContext, variables: [], label: null, iconURI: null, tooltip: null, dirty: false, closeable: true, description: null), EventType=SET} to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@535fedbc
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Cannot initialize Drop
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DND.error(DND.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DND.error(DND.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.<init>(DropTarget.java:138)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPTextEditor.createDrop(JSPTextEditor.java:945)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPTextEditor.createPartControl(JSPTextEditor.java:421)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor$3.createPartControl(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:572)
    at org.jboss.tools.vpe.preview.editor.VpvEditorPart.createPartControl(VpvEditorPart.java:411)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditorPart.addPage(JSPMultiPageEditorPart.java:93)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.createPagesForVPE(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:592)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.createPages(JSPMultiPageEditor.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4561)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3098)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3068)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.lambda$0(OpenWithMenu.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

After some googling I came to the conclusion that it had to do with the JBoss tools xhtml editor, and I tried to open the xhtml file with the html editor and it worked. I have also discoverd that all the other JBoss tools editors do not work with eclipse 2020-03.
As a workaround I have changed the file assosiations to non JBoss tools editors. However I'm not happy with that workaround, does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please format logs as _Code Sample_ (not as _Blockquote_) to prevent the loss of line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's been fixed for their next release atop 2020-03: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-27138. You'll have to stay on 2019-12 until it's released.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to live with my workaround until than.